# Go Cardless API - how to know who has subscriptions

Tags: php, gocardless

Very quick and simple question for anyone who has used go-cardless before.

I have read the docs (I think - may have missed this :-P) and am just struggling with one point:

New Pre-authorisation sent - fine

Return to my server - fine

However - from the information sent back it does not return any identifying information for the customer other than the customers unique ID.

Soooo - how do I then confirm that person has a valid subscription / pre-authorisation?

I know I could do this via sessions and then link the ID returned to the customer that way but that seems fraught with security problems and problems if a session fails for any reason.

What is the correct way of doing this?

I am guessing that somehow I can use the unique ID returned to then request that clients actual info but I cannot find how to do this either!

https://developer.gocardless.com <- here are the documents for the company.

Please tell me I am just being thick and have missed an obvious step.

Here is what is returned after successful payment / subscription

```
GoCardless_PreAuthorization Object
(
[client] => GoCardless_Client Object
    (
        [account_details] => Array
            (
                [app_id] => XXXXXXX
                [app_secret] => XXXXXXX
                [merchant_id] => XXXXXXX
                [access_token] => XXXXXXX
            )

        [base_url] => https://sandbox.gocardless.com
        [redirect_uri] => 
    )

[max_amount] => 100.0
[setup_fee] => 0.0
[currency] => GBP
[interval_length] => 1
[interval_unit] => month
[name] => 
[description] => 
[status] => active
[remaining_amount] => 100.0
[next_interval_start] => 2014-06-01T00:00:00Z
[expires_at] => 
[created_at] => 2014-05-01T07:04:20Z
[merchant_id] => XXXXXXXXXXXX
[user_id] => XXXXXXXEE54543 // this is the unique ID for user
[id] => XXXXX83854943 // // this is the unique ID for this preauthorisation.
[uri] => https://sandbox.gocardless.com/api/v1/pre_authorizations/XXXXXXX
[sub_resource_uris] => Array
    (
        [bills] => https://sandbox.gocardless.com/api/v1/merchants/XXXXXXXX/bills?source_id=XXXXXXXX
    )

)
```

**EDIT**

I am passing the following:

```
$payment_details = array(
'max_amount'      => '100.00',
'interval_length' => 1,
'interval_unit'   => 'month',
'user'    => array(
    'first_name'  => 'xxxx',
    'last_name'   => 'yyyy',
    'email'       => 'test@test.com'
 ),
    'state' => 'abc123456789',
    'setup_fee' => '40.00'
 );
```

`state` SHOULD get passed back -> but I am not sure why it isn't????

Thanks in advance!

p.s. no idea what tags this comes under as API is just horrific - PHP and go-cardless are best I could do!## Heading ##!!!!

Answer (score 0):

"State" gets passed back via a GET parameter.

Set up a custom redirect page and after a customer confirms a subscription and lands on the custom page, you will see the GET parameters in the URL.

The object you are seeing is fetched using those GET parameters.